# Java Substitute Values In A Table

Tags: java

To save time on calculations, I am making a program that will use formula to calculate a value based on the data that the user inputs. The program will prompt the user for five double values: A, B, and C, D, and E. It will then multiply A by B and then find the corresponding value on a conversion table. It will do the same for C and D and plug in the corresponding values along with E in a formula to give the user the answer. My question is: How would I include the table of values I mentioned above into my program so that I can easily find the corresponding values? I'm thinking of hardcoding these values into hashmaps but that would take quite awhile. Is there a file format that stores similar types of data that would be optimal to the situation?

[image: table]

Comment: What ideas do you have? Why don't you at least present some ideas, so we can provide feedback on them.

Comment: where is your program?

Comment: My first impulse would be to hard code these values into a hashmap but it would take awhile.

Comment: How many values will there be, we see less than 100 on the screen, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in CSV.  Load the values into an custom object/class with a field for each column.  Start by looping over the entire set of objects to find the correct value/range each time.  If that does not perform well optimize by doing things like having multiple lists of references to the objects where each list is sorted by a different column-- use those sorted lists to quickly find the correct object.

I say "range" here, because I am assuming you are sometimes looking for doubles.  If the result of your calculation tells you to look for 1.999999 you may actually have to look for that +/- some tolerance.  For this same reason you wouldn't want to use doubles as the keys for a map.